# Computer game in Haskell — widget toolkit wanted

Tags: user-interface, haskell, sdl

I am writing a small RTS game in Haskell, and the time has come to
create some GUI for it (buttons, menus and such).  However, I don't
have any experience in GUI toolkit creation, so I would be thankful
for ideas on how to choose right data types, event handling routines
and such.

Desired functionality: menu screens (main, load/save, settings,
network game), text inputs, game interface (main screen (C&C-like)
with buttons, selects and checkboxes.

My current approach is to represent the whole GUI as a state machine
that has a number of states and transitions between them that are
triggered when an event arrives:

```
-- Local client state.  Actual game state is stored on the server
-- and is updated/synced separately.
data ClientState = […]

-- Keyboard state, mouse state, quadtree of clickables, list of
-- widgets.
data UIState = […]

uiCycle :: UIState -> ClientState -> IO ()
uiCycle uiState clientState = do
  event <- waitEvent
  let widget = findWidget uiState event
  let (uiState', clientStateAction, ioAction) =
        uiTransition widget event uiState clientState
  -- Update game state (execute game logic).
  let clientState' = clientStateAction clientState
  -- Redraw appropriate surfaces etc.
  ioAction
  uiCycle uiState' clientState'
```

Widget is something like

```
data Widget =
  Widget { wtType          :: WidgetType
         , wtParent        :: Maybe Widget
         --, wtRelated       :: [Widget] -- Feels hacky.
         , wtBox           :: Rect
         , wtPosition      :: WidgetPosition
         , wtAnchors       :: [WidgetAnchor]
         , wtEventHandlers :: Map Event EventHandler
         , wtDisabled      :: Bool
         }
```

where

```
type EventHandler = (Event -> (UIState, ClientState) ->
                    (UIState, ClientState, IO ()))
```

When an event comes and appropriate widget is found, my program looks
for a handler for this kind of event in `wtEventHandlers` for this widget,
and executes an action if such handler is found.

When a widget is created, its rect is added to a `QuadTree`, which is
queried by `findWidget`.  The tree is updated when widgets are created
or removed.

However, it is very difficult to program in that way because UI states
are already numerous (even for a simple UI with a few buttons and no
menus).

I thought about implementing each widget as a state machine and
composing these machines so that the number of states and transitions
will be reduced.  Perhaps it would be good to wrap it into a monad (like
it is done in XMonad).

Things I have looked at:

- pygame dot org/tags/gui ← didn't get any usable ideas because
  everything there is very object-oriented;
- http://joyridelabs.de/game/code/ ← not applicable because they use
  Qt and I don't want such dependency;
- http://www.scribd.com/doc/19503176/The-Design-and-Implementation-of-xmonad

My questions are:

- Does describing widgets as state machines that "react" to certain events and "ignore" all others make sense to a widget toolkit designer?  Is there a better (easier) way?
- Is organizing interface description into a `Monad` a good idea?

E. g.

```
mkGameScreenButtons = runGuiDef $ do
  panicExitButton /// MouseDown ==> liftM exitGameNow
  panicExitButton /// MouseIn ==> do hideGameScreen
                                     muteSounds
                                     muteMusic
  panicExitButton /// MouseOut ==> do unhideGameScreen
                                      unmuteSounds
                                      unmuteMusic
  gameSpeedSlider /// MouseUp ==> changeSpeed (wtValue gameSpeedSlider)
  [...]
 where panicExitButton = mkButton (5, 5) [AnchorTop, AnchorRight] "BOSS BUTTON"
 [...]
```

- Is there any relevant literature I could read before moving further?  Emphasis on functional approach would be nice.
- Is there a way to avoid writing a widget toolkit altogether?  I want my game to be able to run in fullscreen mode, so Gtk2hs won't work.

Comment: You should have a look at Functional Reactive Programming (FRP). Known libraries are reactive-banana and Yampa (or the newer Animas fork). The first one also has a wxHaskell binding, where you can get a feel for how FRP integrates with GUIs.

Comment: "I want my game to be able to run in fullscreen mode, so Gtk2hs won't work." <- gtk apps are fully capable of running in fullscreen mode...

Comment: btw if its of any use you can have a look at my simple RTS implemented in Haskell at https://github.com/yairchu/defend . I don't have any menus/buttons etc, like you I need to add them..

Comment: @bzn: thanks for the tip!  I'm looking at Yampa+SDL right now, they seem to be working together just fine